# Applying condition on localfield in aggregate in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two collections `user` and `transaction`, transaction has two fields `customer` and `seller` , and user has two fields `name` and `email`., user collection contains data of customers and sellers

I want output as if the `email` passed belongs to `customer` then `seller` details should come from lookup and if `email` passed belongs to `seller` then `customer` details should come from lookup

What I have done is, I am passing the value `email` dynamically , `email` value can belongs to `customer` or `seller` , If `email` matches `seller` then I want the `localfield` in lookup as `customer` and vice versa. Following is what I have tried.

```
const email = req.email;

transaction.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      $or: [{
          customer: email,
        },
        {
          seller: email,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "user",
      localField: {
        $cond: [{
          if: {
            $eq: ["$customer", email]
          },
          then: "seller",
          else: "customer",
        }],
      },
      foreignField: "email",
      as: "user",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$user"
  },
]);
```

But for the above query error comes as below

```
$lookup argument 'localField' must be a string
```

I am using nodejs, express and mongoose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `localField` allows only string, you can use [lookup with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries),

- `let` to define your conditions logic
- `pipeline` to put your matching condition with lookup collection's field

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "user",
        let: {
            localField: {
                $cond: [{
                    if: { $eq: ["$customer", email] },
                    then: "$seller",
                    else: "$customer",
                }]
            }
        },
        pipeline: [
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$email", "$$localField"] } } }
        ],
        as: "user"
    }
}
```

Comment: `$cond` value in this case should be just an object from the array

Comment: @SemyonVyskubov not getting you exactly.